# Modelling a situation in spring mvc with jpa and hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

I have a situation in modelling a system of online auction like there will be items which will be posted
for auction with their features and all. now there will be bidders bidding for it. Here ultimately when one bid will be accepted that bideer will be attached with that item.  now i have an "item" table which stores all details about the item. so how to realise this one to one relationship in jpa annotation. because when item is being posted for auction then i don't know which bidder's bid will be accepted.
so how to use `@OneToOne` here using jpa.

or should i model the problem in different way like two table one for auction item posted and item bid accepted. because when bid accpted then i know the bidder details.so there i can use `@OneToOne` easily.please give some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

`@OneToOne` doesn't imply that the bidder exists. It will be null until the end of auction, at which time you will set it to whoever won the auction. BTW, I assume one bidder can bid for many items, in which case it is `@ManyToOne` on the item side, and `@OneToMany` on bidder side.